# Storyboard view controller with different function

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue

I am new to storyboard programming. I have designed a storyboard (say SB1), it have two funcitons in its viewcontroller. I have another storyboard (SB2) and it has two buttons. From both buttons I want to show SB1, but when I press button1, then func1 should executed and if I pressing button2, then fun2 should be executed. Any suggestions.

My code below.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? StotyBoard1ViewController
        where segue.identifier == "LocatorSegue" {
            viewController.func1()
    }
    //how to invoke SB1 Func2 from here
}


@IBAction func button1Click(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SB1Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func button2Click(sender: AnyObject) {
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SB1Segue", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do somthing like this:-

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
    var sender: UIButton?

    func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? StotyBoard1ViewController {
        if segue.identifier == "SB1Segue" {
            if self.sender == button1 {
                viewController.func1()
            } else if self.sender == button2 {
                 viewController.func2()
            }
        }
   } 

    @IBAction func button1Click(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.sender = sender as! UIButton
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SB1Segue", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func button2Click(sender: AnyObject) {
    {
        self.sender = sender as! UIButton
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SB1Segue", sender: self)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a `BOOL` type of Global Variable let us say `isCallFunc1` in your `SB1` class, now in your `prepareForSegue` assign the value of that `BOOL` variable as true of false for different button action like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as? StotyBoard1ViewController
        if segue.identifier == "SB1Segue" {
            viewController.isCallFunc1 = true
    } else {
            viewController.isCallFunc1 = false
    }
}
```

Now in `viewWillAppear` of SB1 as per the BOOL variable you have to call appropriate function like

```
if isCallFunc1 {
    function1()
} else {
    function2()
}
```

Also change the identifier of button2Click to differentiate between the identifiers

```
@IBAction func button1Click(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SB1Segue", sender: self)
}

@IBAction func button2Click(sender: AnyObject) {
{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SB1SegueOther", sender: self)
}
```